# Are questions about a phrase only heard in a song acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is asking a question about something heard in a song acceptable?

Songs are well known to twist grammar, change the word order, or change the pronunciation of words. While songs use expressions also used in other contexts, they don't use only those expressions. If an expression is not used outside the context of song lyrics, chances are the expression should not be used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such a question might be Too Localized on ELU, but I think it would be proper here. A Learner has really no way of knowing whether something unfamiliar she hears in a song is a nonce-expression or a colloquialism. A dictionary won't tell her; she has to ask.

Comment: I doubt English learners has only songs as source of learning. If a phrase is only heard in a song, it is probably better avoiding to use it.

Comment: @kiam sure, but how do you know if it is only heard in the song?

Comment: It's pretty easy: If the OP mention only the song, it is probable there is where the phrase was heard. I take the assumption users are already used to "songs cannot be taken as example of what can be acceptably said in a normal conversation" as reply, to which they reply saying where else they heard the phrase.

Comment: @kiamlaluno  Songs are not *necessarily* taken as, &c. The same thing can be said of the New York Times, the works of Bertrand Russell, the lease on your apartment and, for that matter, about every third sentence in ordinary conversation. Language is language.

Answer (score 2):

Questions concerning song phrases aren't inherently off-topic, but the question you are surely thinking of  ("Is "[location] welcome to" correct?") is not a great question as it is clear that the matter is on artistic license, not on English grammar.  Historically, questions about songs have been allowed on EL&U, for example, as long as it was otherwise reasonably answerable. However the asker has just to make sure theirself "song question" is a grammar one; whether or not it references a song should be tangential to the primary question. Otherwise, it probably fits best on songs.SE.

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to just be about grammar. The limitation on ELU is that it is _answerable_ (and grammar often falls under this). So a question like "What does Rihanna mean by 'umbrella'?" is totally speculative so bad for SE. But a question like "What is the rhyme scheme of 'Umbrella'?" is OK.

Comment: It's not 'clear' that it's not on English grammar unless you already know the answer. This is a site for people for whom such things are not 'clear'.